# Decrypting an account from keystore generates the error - Cannot read property 'kdf' of undefined

Tags: web3js

I need to sign a transaction and send to infura using a keystore. I ran into the following error while calling the decrypt function.

```
if (json.crypto.kdf === 'scrypt') {
                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kdf' of undefined
at Accounts.decrypt
```

I am using `web3 v1.0.0-beta.36`

This is my code, any help is appreciated

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/f..."));
var fs = require('fs');

const contractAddress = "0x...";
const sendingAccount = "0x...";
const password = "...";

var abiArray = JSON.parse(getAbi());
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray,contractAddress);

const keystore = fs.readFileSync("UTC--...", 'utf8');
const decryptedAccount = 
web3.eth.accounts.decrypt(JSON.parse(keystore), password);
```

Comment: I would suggest to place a console.log(keystore); just before last line and check if the Json is in V3 format like the one specified here: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html#decrypt

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you managed to do it or not but for anyone else that has this problem and ends up here.

I had the same problem. I was generating the keystore from myEtherWallet and the JSON instead of the key "crypto" it had "Crypto". Changed it to lowercase and worked.